# How to Invert column values in pandas - pythonic way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                    'Label':[1,1,1,0,0]})
```

My objective is to

a) replace `0s` as `1s` AND `1s` as `0s` in `Label` column

I was trying something like the below

```
cdf.assign(invert_label=cdf.Label.loc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)) #not work
cdf['invert_label'] = np.where(cdf['Label']==0, '1', '0')
```

'
but this doesn't work. It reverses the order

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
    Id  Label
0   1   0
1   2   0
2   3   0
3   4   1
4   5   1
```

Comment: `cdf['invert_label'] = np.where(cdf['Label']==0, '1', '0')` not working for you? for me working

Comment: `df.Label ^= 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare `0`, so for `0` get `True`s and for not `0` get `False`s, then converting to integers for mapping `True, False` to `1, 0`:

```
print (cdf['Label'].eq(0))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: Label, dtype: bool

cdf['invert_label'] = cdf['Label'].eq(0).astype(int)

print (cdf)
   Id  Label  invert_label
0   1      1             0
1   2      1             0
2   3      1             0
3   4      0             1
4   5      0             1
```

Another idea is use mapping:

```
cdf['invert_label'] = cdf['Label'].map({1:0, 0:1})

print (cdf)
   Id  Label  invert_label
0   1      1             0
1   2      1             0
2   3      1             0
3   4      0             1
4   5      0             1
```

Answer (score 1):

One maybe obvious answer might be to use `1-value`:

```
cdf['Label2'] = 1-cdf['Label']
```

output:

```
   Id  Label  Label2
0   1      1       0
1   2      1       0
2   3      1       0
3   4      0       1
4   5      0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the `not` function as well -

```py
import operator
cdf['Label'].map(operator.not_).astype('int')
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way, and I am adding this as a separate answer as this is probably not "pythonic" enough (in the sense that it is not very explicit) is to use the bitwise `xor`

```
cdf['Label'] ^ 1
```